# BibTex and Overleaf. Citations not working

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, overleaf

I am trying to add a bibliography to my Overleaf latex document and for that I am using BibTex.

I downloaded a `.bib` file from Zotero which automatically generates them for you and imported it into my Overleaf project. The file is named `security_policy.bib`. Then I added the `\bibliogray` and `\bibliography` tags at the end of the document (before `\end{document}`):

```
\backmatter
\bibliographystyle{hispa}
\bibliography{security_policy.bib}
```

I am trying to cite ISO/IEC 27002 which is referenced by the bib file as "27_iso/iec_2008". As I start typing `\cite`, the reference "27_iso/iec_2008" automatically pops up, which means the bibliography has been correctly imported.

However, when the PDF document is generated (which according to the official Overleaf examples and guides automatically runs bibtex therefore creating the bibliography references), the cite is missing (it is showing `[?]` instead).

What should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: You may be missing the file `hispa.bst` in your project, which isn't available on Overleaf by default, since it's not included in CTAN. Does uploading a copy of `hispa.bst` to your project help? (If you're the user who emailed Overleaf support about a very similar issue, I've just responded to you.)

Comment: Yes, that's it, and yes, that was me! I didn't upload the bst file. I wish Overleaf would have given me a heads up about that! I thought it was a predefined style, like plain.

Comment: Did you look in the log file?

Comment: @dabadaba Indeed – we'll improve the warning/error message reporting mechanism in this respect, thanks! :-)

Comment: is this a bug or a feature? never had this issue with papers written on overleaf, just with my thesis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be missing the file `hispa.bst` in your project, which isn't available on Overleaf by default, since it's not included in TeX Live. Uploading a copy of `hispa.bst` (via Overleaf's `Add files > Upload` menu) to your project should (and have) help.

Comment: What is the significance of the name of this file? "hispa"